# iOS App Store Submission: Missing icon (Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

I am making a Cordova (PhoneGap) app and have submitted it to the App Store. However, I've received an email with the following message:

```
Invalid Icon Path - No icon found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIcons": icon-72@2x.png
```

Now, being very new to any iOS programming and having made the app in Cordova as opposed to the traditional methods, I cannot really figure this out. I am not sure what CFBundleIcons is. Here's what my .plist file looks like:

[image: plist]

If anyone can give me any advice on how to fix this that would be great! Thanks

Comment: Right click the plist and select "show raw keys/values".  Then find and edit the value in question.

Comment: thanks that seem to have worked ok!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodaFi's answer is correct:

> Right click the plist and select "show raw keys/values". Then find and edit the value in question

Answer (score 1):

Actually the default Cordova project include a reference to the icon name in the plist file, but not the actual picture. You have to drag and drop the picture in the Ressources/Icon