# Xcode 5: "Invalid image path" CFBundleIcons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Ok, my problem seems to be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532485/ios-app-store-submission-missing-icon-cordova), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240636/invalid-icon-path-error-returned-from-apple-app-store-team), but following the answers, there is not helping me. This might be because I am using Xcode 5, before I upgraded to this version I wasn't having any problems with this app.

When I validate my app I get the following error:

> "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key
>   'CFBundleIcons': 'icon152'"

So I go to the `.plist` file in Xcode, right click `Show Raw Keys/Values` and find `CFBundleIcons`.

There is a tree that looks like this:

```
▼ CFBundleIcons                  Dictionary
    ▼ CFBundlePrimaryIcon        Dictionary
        ▼ CFBundleIconFiles      Array
             Item 0              String       icon152
```

Now I've renamed `icon152` to `icon152.png`, and it still doesn't work. Does this value require the full path to the image on my mac? And if it does, why am I not getting the full path inserted when I add the image from scratch? I've validated apps before and never experienced these problems.

I've tried removing all the icon entries out of the `.plist` file and re-adding them, still doesn't work.

I've tried removing the images from the bundle and Xcode altogether, and completely re-added them from scratch. Still doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If anybody else is struggling with this, all I did to solve it was click the "Use Asset Catalog" button - and all these problems disappeared. You can find that button by clicking on your project in the Navigator, then under General scroll down to App Icons - the button should be there.

Comment: The issue seems like no image exist on the path. Please readd the image to the specific path

Comment: which path should i use? one relative to the app itself, or the full path of where the image is stored on my mac? and why isn't the path being included properly when i add the image?

Comment: Are you adding the image programmatically?

Comment: The image is the icon for the App itself, i am adding it through Xcode. I was not aware that you could add the App icons programmatically - how would this be done?

Comment: Not sure if it works but in info.plist if you can see one icon file is there on that value extension of file should be .icns is it same for you?

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in the `.plist` file any reference to extension of file or to anything named .icn - where should this be?

Comment: It should be in your info.plist file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try removing the icon from the project and adding them again? Then try to use the name without .png.

Sometimes Xcode can't see the changes if you modify the file in Finder.

Comment: "Ive tried removing the images from the bundle and Xcode altogether, and completely re-added them from scratch. Still doesnt work." - as .png or without .png - makes no difference.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running? Newer Xcode allows you to set the image name from the project file instead of editing the plist file. You can try that. If you're running Xcode 5, try looking at Asset Catalogue. Both should work, but it's worth a shot if the first one does not work.

Comment: IM running Xcode 5.0 - I will have a look into the Asset Catalogue

Comment: I clicked on the "Use Asset Catalog" button and all my missing image problems magically disappeared. I didn't have to do anything more... Weird. Many thanks for your help however!

Comment: I clicked on "Use Asset Catalog" and it got rid of all my errors except one... still says I'm missing an `icon.png` where I definitely don't think I am, and it's *very* frustrating.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same error as ckoskar,
    "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':        'icon120x120'"

I ended up deleting the file from the CarPlay section in the AppIcon part of Images.xcassets, and then I was able to submit the build.

Comment: That works, but is not really a solution, as you just ignore the Apple CarPlay Icon :(

Comment: It could be a bug with Apple, since the image size is the same as 2x icon for the iPhone app icon size for iOS 7 and 8 at 120 pt. Might be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: Ran into this too, and removing the 120x120 image I added to the Images.xcassets for "Carplay" did the trick.

Comment: Ran into this too, and removing the 120x120 image I added to the Images.xcassets for "Carplay" did the trick. I filed a bug, it's still an issue with Xcode 6.1 and 6.3.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.4 and still had to remove the Carplay asset. Still an issue.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, and the  "Use Asset Catalog" worked for me. Maybe take it out of the resources, put it back in, clean, build and then see if it works.

To find this button : Project > General > App Icons and Launch Images
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Select the Target
2. Go to Build Phases
3. Expand the Copy Bundle Resources
4. Go to the bottom of the panel and select the + sign.
5. Add each of the missing resources.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I forgot to add the image files to the project.

Answer (score 7):

I too had the same issue, the interesting thing was that I was already using the asset catalog when this happened. The solution that ended up working for me is described here: 
[Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path. CFBundleIcons Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522042/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-cfbundleicons-xcode-5)

Basically you need to add the image to the target you are building. To do that, select the image in the list of files under your project in the **Navigation Pane**, then show the **Utilities Pane** on the right and check the target under **Target Membership** in the **Utilities Pane** to the left

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes that happens when you add files separately.

Make sure you have the *Build name*'s check box checked on the "*Target Membership*" area in the *Utilities* pane.

The files for which it is throwing an error would have that check box unchecked hence it does not get included in the final build.

By checking this checkbox I got my problem solved. Thank DomandoCoder!

Answer (score 3):

I had problem with:

> "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'icon120x120'"

The solution was to move the icon (120x120) to a another appicon folder

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I was trying to get a Free and Full version app to upload.  The free app TARGET uploaded fine though I had problems with the Paid TARGET.  I selected all the images used for icons in the PAID and FREE versions and then looked at : FILE INSPECTOR --> TAGET MEMBERSHIP -> make sure to check them both and then it'll be OK.  Worked for me.
Here's the error I had:
[image]

Then I selected and checked these for PAID and FREE versions of the app:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well for me it was not any of these.  I kept adding and cleaning to no avail

there was  list of icons in the plist under:

CFBundleIconFiles~ipad and CFBundleIconFiles

There were a few in there that did not exist. I removed/ updated and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image is added to the project:

1. expand the Resources folder
2. if the file is there remove it
3. if the file is not there add it by right clicking the Resources folder
4. clean the build and rebuild

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with an **error** about **iTunesArtwork** and **warning** about **120 icon** and the "**Use Asset Catalog**" worked for me where I filled the missing icons by dragging from project navigation pane and didn't do anything with **iTunesArtwork** though.

**Edit:**

My previous solution didn't work this time for same error for my react native app. My **faulty icons images** were causing this very issue. I opened one of the icon in Preview and selected the whole image area and created **new image from clipboard**. I replaced all the old images by these newly created images and upload went successful.

Answer (score 1):

What solved to me was to check the icons that are failing and open them in preview and export as png again.

No changes in XCode, only new export of the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this issue if your app icon name aren't correct.

I was using [appicon.co](https://appicon.co) which was generating wrong names that's why I was getting this error. Then I used "Icon Set Creator" iMac app to generate icons & everything worked fine after using them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'icon40x40'"

In my particular case I was just missing the 80x80 (40x40 scale x2) icon in Images.xcassets. The error message excludes the scale of the icon.

Adding the missing size resolved the issue for me.