# Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path. CFBundleIcons Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm trying to update my app for iOS 7 with Xcode 5.0.

Everything works fine, but when I archive then validate I get these messages:

Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key `CFBundleIcons': 'APP-ICON-57'`

I've tried to remove and add the images, have manually edited my `info.plist`, renamed images, add `.png` to the key, etc.  Nothing seems to work.  Please help, I'm about one day into getting through this silly issue.

Comment: For me, it worked strangely when I renamed the png files to jpg and referenced those images, and restarted Xcode.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure that this image is a members of target you are building:

[image]

Also be aware that names are case sensitive.

1. Click on the affected image in the Project Navigator
2. In the utilities window, click the "Show the File Inspector" icon.
3. Ensure the "Target Membership" app name has "v" next to it.
4. Rebuild and archive.

Comment: That solution is awsome

Comment: There's no image in your project. You've selected the UIKit.framework. How is this a solution?

Comment: @JamesBush I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. 
I improved an answer a bit - step 3 - makes sure "v" is next to Target Membership item ( the big red area on the right)

Answer (score 136):

iOS 8/xCode 6 answer, if you get an error AppIcon 120x120 not found, uncheck the car play icon in xcode's AppIcon set. Assuming you're not using car play of course

Comment: Uncheck the car play == drop from AppIconSet. Thanks !! By the way, I hope this bug will be fix in the next version.

Comment: You, sir, are a champion.

Comment: This should be ALL the way up! Just figured this out myself and couldn't believe it isn't in any of the so-answers.

Comment: The CarPlay option is not checked by default; and, what if you wanted it? This is not a solution.

Answer (score 28):

If you get an error AppIcon 120x120 not found in Xcode 6, 
1. click images.xassets which is located left side right under Main.storyboard.
2. You should see bunch of same icons in different size.
3. At the bottom, find one that says CarPlay iOS 8 120pt.
4. Delete this icon and leave it blank.
Problem solved!

Comment: You are just repeating my answer?

Comment: this answers tells exact steps

Comment: It was a horrible answer, and there's no CarPlay icon placeholder in the Asset Catalog.

Answer (score 16):

I encountered the same problem. The solution is to look under the "Supporting Files" and "foobar-info.plist" file (see attached). Under the Icon Files if you click the down arrows, you will come across the offending file names.

[image: xcode 5 foobar-info.plist]

Comment: I accidentally added an icon with the wrong name and removed it from my resources (the reference) but when archiving and distributing to the App Store I got an error saying it could not find that image. It was still referenced through the .plist so thanks for this.

Comment: Helpful, thanks! I use an asset catalogue, but before had used single image files. And these are still stored in the info.plist as you describe. I just removed the entries in the plist and everything went well.

Answer (score 8):

it's working

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

go to your project "Info" tab

and Remove the properties of “Icon file” and “Icon files”

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue using Ionic Framework. The iOS config it generates seems to be broken. Deleted everything containing image from info -> worked.

Comment: it works for me, Instead of adding icons here better is to remove these options

Answer (score 5):

In my Cordova 6 / iOS 4 project in xCode 9 I needed to go to ProjectName.plist under the resources folder. There was a key named Icon which had the offending Icon.png value beside it. Deleted the key and now all working.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I solve it by uncheck the carPlay from Images.xcassets.

Go to Images.xcassets then choose appIcon, then uncheck carPlay

Comment: This was the fix for me.

Comment: Another one repeating my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If it happens with 120x120 icon, just delete it from images.xcassets.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out the affected image was of type JPEG even though the extension was PNG.

Check it under document type in Preview.

[image: Document type: JPEG image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

If you generate Icons using Prep App or https://makeappicon.com/

You might get this Error

[image]

> If you are not developing App for Car Play or Apple Watch Or Mac it's better to remove its corresponding icons and uncheck them

To remove and uncheck them from Xcode :

> => Click on the Property Tab on Right-Hand side
>
> => Goto the Third Sub Tab
>
> => Uncheck Car Play [ ] All
> => Apple Watch -> None 
> => Uncheck Mac [ ] All

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I for the appIcon60x60 file.  I found that my appicon60@2x was a 60x60 file when it should have been a 120x120 file.

The carplay icon had a similar problem.  While Xcode says it's a 1x file, it's actually a 2x file.  So when i created and appicon120@2x file where the image was 240x240, it corrected the problem.  This is a defect in Xcode as it should have indicated a 2x file instead of 1x.

In summary, if you are getting this error, check that the actual image sizes match up with the corresponding icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem in Xcode 7.

[image]

When I check the Apple official documentation for the app icon:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

I checked very icon and the exactly size,I have set all we can set the icon,I have solved this problem at last.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna share my solution, too because all these answers did not help me really.

I had the same problem just in my case it was Icon 29x29 and 40x40.

First of all funny thing. If you wanna able to READ the entire error message (yea Epic Fail Apple Xcode 8) in my case the first Error message was cut, I could not even read it fully, create your App with

> Xcode -> Archive -> Export

and then create your file and then verify it

> Xcode -> Application Loader -> import and upload to App Store

Only there you will see all error messages in full length.

anyhow let's assume you know which Icons are wrong

You have to go the folder Project Folder and then in my case it was

> Unity-iPhone-> Images.xaccets->AppIcon.appiconset -> Contents.json

Open that file and simply delete all image objects that was shown in the error message

in my case

```
    {
        "filename" : "Icon-Small.png",
        "idiom" : "iphone",
        "scale" : "1x",
        "size" : "29x29"
    },
    {
        "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
        "idiom" : "iphone",
        "scale" : "2x",
        "size" : "29x29"
    },
    {
        "filename" : "Icon-Small@3x.png",
        "idiom" : "iphone",
        "scale" : "3x",
        "size" : "29x29"
    },
    {
        "filename" : "Icon-Small-80.png",
        "idiom" : "iphone",
        "scale" : "2x",
        "size" : "40x40"
    },
    {
        "filename" : "Icon-Small-120.png",
        "idiom" : "iphone",
        "scale" : "3x",
        "size" : "40x40"
    }
```

**NOW IMPROTANT**
You have to Shut XCode 8 because if you try to save the file it WILL NOT WORK.
Even if you click Save anyways (what a epic fail Apple) it will not do. So you think you saved but you did not . . . it took me hours to figure this out because I thought that XCode was rebuilding the json file automatically.

so that was my fix :)

Hope it helps for anyone

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and fixed a different solution which is not all other from above.

My solution was image format. I received an image with .png extension but the image is not png. It was .psd file... This error is same with all other. 
Should be careful it.