# Invalid image path when deploying via Delphi xe6

Tags: ios, delphi, deployment, delphi-xe6

I am encountering this error when uploading an iOS app to the App Store:
"Invalid Image Path.......CFBundleIconFiles: Icon120 at Software Assets/Software Asset....."

I have found articles fixing this issue when using XCode, however, I am using Delphi xe6.
[Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path. CFBundleIcons Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522042/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-cfbundleicons-xcode-5)

I checked the images - they are there. In fact, when deploying an Ad Hoc release to an iPhone, it works fine. Icons are there and no errors. I've tried renaming images, manually deleting the appName.info.plist and completely deleting the contents of the PA Server output directory.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... No way to toggle between using Asset Catalogs, so I then assumed that Delphi was just using them for App Store deployment. After build/compile, I manually deleted the CFBundleIconFile in the .plist file.