# App not validating because no path under CFBundleIcons, but CFBundleIcons is not in plist

Tags: ios, xcode6

I'm getting 'Invalid Image Path - No image found at path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon120x120'.

I thought the solution would be to remove that key from the plist but I checked and CFBundleIcons is not even in my plist. Is there another way I can access this key and remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS 8/xCode 6, delete the Car Play Icon from your AppIcon set. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195423/3294779