# ios validation: Invalid image path - missing icon file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

i want to upload my first app (in swift) into apple ios store but i get some errors on validation. I've been searching for many hours (on internet) to fix it but i cannot find a solution.

Error 1:
Invalid Image Path -  No Image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons'

This key is empty in info.plist. I've added all icons to a Images.xcassets (no CarPlay icon, plz see images)

Error 2:
Missing required icon file: The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone/iPod Touch exactly '120x120' pixels, in png format iOS versiona >= 7.0.

Images:
[Picture 1](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3915/yphn3gsx_jpg.htm)
[Picture 2](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3915/4bt4e9ac_jpg.htm)

It would be great to get a little bit help. thx forward

Comment: Are these really `errors` (red) or `warnings` (yellow) ? Warnings on missing icons wont lead to app rejection.

Comment: Hi, as you can see in picture 1 it is an red alert. thx

Comment: Possibel duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522042/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-cfbundleicons-xcode-5/26195423#26195423

Answer (score 1):

1) you're using the `Images.xcassets`, you dont need the `CFBundleIcon` property in the `info.plist` anymore since the build will actually compile the values into the compiled info.plist.

2) Need to add app icon 120*120 size icon in `appIcon` list of `Images.xcassets` for second error.

Comment: Hi,
thx for your help.

I've removed the CFBundleIcons key from the info.plist and add a AppIcon120x120.png icon.

I got already the same error on validation. I've cleaned and rebuild the project before analyzing.

Answer (score 0):

i used [makeappicon](http://makeappicon.com) to create a new iconset and replaced the appiconset with the generated files. Now everything is working right. Thx all

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked here: [Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path. CFBundleIcons Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522042/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-cfbundleicons-xcode-5/26195423#26195423)

iOS 8/xCode 6 answer, if you get an error AppIcon 120x120 not found, uncheck the car play icon in xcode's AppIcon set. Assuming you're not using car play of course

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195423/1238867

Comment: Hi, 
there wasn't an car play icon activated! I have read many articles on internet before i asked here. 
But i already found a solution (read above). Thx for help