# Xcode 6: “Invalid image path” CFBundleIcons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

when I try to put the application through xcode crashes this error

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqmj.png]

I read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316501/xcode-5-invalid-image-path-cfbundleicons) questions but nothing helped , because when I click Show Raw Keys / Values ​​reflect nothing because CFBundleIcons no subdirectories. This is my .plist

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McweE.png]

PS Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources on this way I lit red file main.storyboard, and in the list is highlighted in red appTest.xctest,

Comment: Check the image.xcasset folder

Comment: I do not know what you mean , but image.xcasset folder is butchered on the folder , and in it lay the image ( 1x, 2x , 3x) and json file

Comment: In your xcode project there will be a folder like that. Open it in xcode and check

Comment: that's what I see in this folder 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/zFE2R.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/2PJEn.png

all right ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error before, and none of my previous methods to fix it worked this last time. I tried recreating the assets catalog. I tried deleting the "car play" icon. Nothing was working. My problem with this one this time was that my 120x120 icon file was NOT actually 120x120 pixels. I have done this in the past with other resolutions, and I usually get a compile error pointing out that my icon file is not correct. But with the 120x120 icon file, it gives this other error. It can't find a 120x120 icon file at the path specified. The path is correct, but my icon file was some other resolution. Once I corrected that, it finally worked.