# Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':'AppIcon20x20'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

REPOSTING SINCE I AM GETTING NO ANSWERS ON THIS.

I have been struggling with this issue for over a week. Whenever I try to validate a build or use application loader lately I have been getting this error:

```
iTunes Store operation failed. 
Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':'AppIcon20x20'
```

Now, the problem is there is no AppIcon20x20 key in my plist.

Here's my AppIcon asset and attributes settings: 
[AppIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyooc.png), [Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkmmY.png)

Nowhere is a 20x20 asset even mentioned in my Plist, as seen by the source code version here :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon603x.png</string>
                <string>icon602x.png</string>
                <string>icon403x.png</string>
                <string>icon402x.png</string>
                <string>icon293x.png</string>
                <string>icon292x.png</string>
                <string>icon203x.png</string>
                <string>icon203x.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>https://millsfitnessapparel.myshopify.com/</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And lastly, I have googled the heck out of this topic and they all say to just add CFBundleIcons to your plist, which I did, but it's still throwing the error. I have also done this in versions of this project where there are pods, no pods, workspaces, regular xcproj. files, and even with 1 view controller and just some icons [this latest build].

I have also tried to achive this build in xcode versions 8.1, 8.2, and 8.3, all receiving the same error.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. These are apps for a client and I am currently late on delivering because of this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I know you already got answer but its for other coming here.
You can get this issue if your app icon name aren't correct. I was using appicon.co which was generating wrong names that's why I was getting this error. Then I used "Icon Set Creator" iMac app to generate icons & everything worked fine after using them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can simply create your app icons asset using https://makeappicon.com/. You have to supply a 1536x1536px image for the best result. It will automatically create all the app icons for your project

Also please refer to the following:-

- Check the icon file's name is exactly same as the name in your info.plist.  It's fine while running debug mode though, It doesn't work while you upload/ validate the build.
- Please check your app's bundle identifier is correct.

Comment: Still, you can't resolve this. Please post the screenshot of your app icon's asset folder and content.json

Comment: if Non of the above worked please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316501/xcode-5-invalid-image-path-cfbundleicons?rq=1

Comment: I have posted the screenshot, its in the main message.

Comment: Here's the contents.json: `{
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}`

Comment: The make app icon was the answer, it's now uploading. Thanks!

Comment: makeappicon.com will automatically generate all the icons set for our app including ipad and iwatch

Comment: I have now struck the same problem. I have been using 9.3 as a deployment target and never had a problem. I changed deployment target to 11.3 - and that did not cause a problem, however, I then switched back to 9.3 and the problem occurred, I tied 10 and the problem persisted, when I switch back to 11.3 the problem disappears. 
I suspect it could be an Xcode bug.

Comment: This worked for me too thanks. I think the issue was wrong names initially but using makeappicon to generate the icons worked like a charm

Comment: I don't have icons names in info.plist at all, is it suppose to add there itself when I add app icons?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil you don't need this if you are using xcassets.

Comment: This actually worked for me, using AppIcon.co did not really help out, thanks man for your help